# BottomSheetDialogFragment - listen to dismissed by user event

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment, bottom-sheet

How can I listen to a FINAL dismissal of a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`? I want to save user changes on the final dismissal only...

I tried following:

**Method 1**

This only fires, if the dialog is dismissed by swiping it down (not on back press or on touch outside)

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Dialog d = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    d.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

            BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;   
            FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) dialog.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);

            BottomSheetBehavior behaviour = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
            behaviour.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            behaviour.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                    if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN)
                    {
                        // Bottom Sheet was dismissed by user! But this is only fired, if dialog is swiped down! Not if touch outside dismissed the dialog or the back button
                        Toast.makeText(MainApp.get(), "HIDDEN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dismiss();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
    return d;
}
```

**Method 2**

This does not allow me to distinguish between a final dismissal and one that is coming from a screen rotation or activity recreation...

```
 @Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)
{
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    // this works fine but fires one time too often for my use case, it fires on screen rotation as well, although this is a temporarily dismiss only
    Toast.makeText(MainApp.get(), "DISMISSED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Question**

How can I listen to an event that indicates, that the user has finished the dialog?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Although all similar questions on SO suggest using `onDismiss` I think following is the correct solution:

```
@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
{
    super.onCancel(dialog);
    Toast.makeText(MainApp.get(), "CANCEL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This fires if:

```
* the user presses back
* the user presses outside of the dialog
```

This fires NOT:

```
* on screen rotation and activity recreation
```

**Solution**

Combine *onCancel* and *BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback.onStateChanged* like following:

```
public class Dailog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
    {
        super.onCancel(dialog);
        handleUserExit();
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Dialog d = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        d.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;
                FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
                BottomSheetBehavior behaviour = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
                behaviour.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN)
                        {
                            handleUserExit();
                            dismiss();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return d;
    }

    private void handleUserExit()
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainApp.get(), "TODO - SAVE data or similar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder why needs to call dismiss() on onStateChanged(). When missed dismiss() , sliding down bottom sheet not fully working.

Comment: Thanks for `onCancel()`. Warning! This and similar solutions would work, if you didn't disable cancellation of BottomSheet (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42154321/prevent-dismissal-of-bottomsheetdialogfragment-on-touch-outside). If you set `bottomSheetDialogFragment.setCancelable(false);`, listeners won't be called!

Answer (score 13):

If you extended from [BottomSheetDialogFragment()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialogFragment) just override in your class

```
 override fun onDismiss(dialog: DialogInterface) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog)
        //Code here
    }
```

This will trigger when **onBackPress** and when you dismiss the dialog by clicking outside of it.

Make sure to NOT set your dialog as cancelable because this will not fire

Answer (score 9):

```
bottomSheetDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
       toast("dismissed");
   }
});
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please provide an explanation why and how your answer solves the problem.

Comment: overriding onDismiss or onCancel is better.

Comment: It seems there's no such method (`setOnDismissListener`) in `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

Comment: you can use `bottomSheet.dialog?.setOnDismissListener`

Answer (score 5):

i achieved this using this simple trick

```
val bottomSheetDialog = FeedbackFormsFragment.createInstance()
bottomSheetDialog.show((activity as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager, BOTTOM_SHEET)


// add some delay to allow the bottom sheet to be visible first so that the dialog is not null

                Handler().postDelayed({
                    bottomSheetDialog.dialog?.setOnDismissListener {

                       // add code here
                    }
                }, 1000)
```

Answer (score 5):

While the method of @prom85 works, there is a different one. If you want to dismiss a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` in one case and retain in the other, it won't work. It will close the dialog in all cases.

For instance, if you entered text inside `EditText` of `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and occasionally clicked outside, it would close the dialog without any warning. I tried https://medium.com/@anitas3791/android-bottomsheetdialog-3871a6e9d538, it works, but in another scenario. When you drag the dialog down, it will dismiss it. If you click outside, it won't show any alert message and won't dismiss the dialog.

So, I used a nice advice of @shijo from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50734566/2914140.

Add these lines to `onActivityCreated` method (or any other life cycle method after `onCreateView`).

```
@Override 
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    View touchOutsideView = getDialog().getWindow()
        .getDecorView()
        .findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.touch_outside);
    touchOutsideView.setOnClickListener(yourClickListener);
}
```

In my case in `yourClickListener` I check the text and show an alert or dismiss the dialog:

```
private fun checkAndDismiss() {
    if (newText == oldText) {
        dismissAllowingStateLoss()
    } else {
        showDismissAlert()
    }
}
```

When you create `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, don't call `setCancelable(false)` as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42679131/2914140 or these methods probably won't work. And maybe don't set `<item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>` in styles or `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)` in `onCreateDialog`.

---

I also tried several ways to override cancel behavior, but they didn't succeed.

```
<style name="BottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
</style>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme)
}

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)

    dialog.setOnShowListener {
        val bottomSheet = dialog.findViewById<View>(
            android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet) as? FrameLayout
        val behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)
        behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
        behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
            }

            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
                //showing the different states.
                when (newState) {
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN -> dismiss() //if you want the modal to be dismissed when user drags the bottomsheet down
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED -> {
                    }
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED -> {
                    }
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING -> {
                    }
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING -> {
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        dialog.setOnCancelListener {
            // Doesn't matter what you write here, the dialog will be closed.
        }
        dialog.setOnDismissListener {
            // Doesn't matter what you write here, the dialog will be closed.
        }
    }

    return dialog
}

override fun onCancel(dialog: DialogInterface?) {
    // Doesn't matter what you write here, the dialog will be closed.
    super.onCancel(dialog)
}

override fun onDismiss(dialog: DialogInterface?) {
    // Doesn't matter what you write here, the dialog will be closed.
    super.onDismiss(dialog)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
bottomSheetDialogFragment.getDialog().setOnDismissListener(dialog -> {
                // code goes here
            });
```

Note, that you should call it after showing `bottomSheetDialogFragment` (`showNow` in my case), otherwise `getDialog()` will return you null.

Comment: not working man

Answer (score 1):

```
LoctSetupDialog loctSetupDialog = new LoctSetupDialog();
        loctSetupDialog.show(requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),"loctSetup");

        loctSetupDialog.getLifecycle().addObserver((LifecycleEventObserver) (source, event) -> {
            if(event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
            {
                refreshLoctName();
            }
        });
```

Comment: use lifecycle..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In an `AppCompatActivity` you can use the following technique:

```
    val mgr = supportFragmentManager
    val callback = object: FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener {
        var count = 0
        override fun onBackStackChanged() {
            // We come here twice, once when the sheet is opened, 
            // once when it's closed.
            if (++count >= 2) {
                mgr.removeOnBackStackChangedListener(this)
                doWhatNeedsToBeDoneWhenTheSheetIsClosed()
            }
        }
    }
    mgr.addOnBackStackChangedListener(callback)
```

Be sure to do the above just before you call `show` on the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a LifecycleObserver that will be notified when the LifecycleOwner changes state lıke that:

```
val yourBottomSheet = BottomSheet()
            
yourBottomSheet.lifecycle.addObserver(LifecycleEventObserver { source, event ->
      // events Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE, Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

BottomSheetDialogFragment extends DialogFragment, that already implements two interfaces: DialogInterface.OnCancelListener and DialogInterface.OnDismissListener.

You can to listen to the closing of the dialogue:

```
override fun onCancel(dialog: DialogInterface) {
    super.onCancel(dialog)
    // you code here
}
```

and

```
override fun onDismiss(dialog: DialogInterface) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog)
    // you code here
}
```

If user close dialog clicking outside a dialog, or user swipe the dialog down, or user click back button, also if you close dialog programmatically calling

```
dialog.?cancel()
```

then both onCancel() and onDismiss() will be invoked.

But if you close dialog programmatically calling method

```
dismiss()
```

then only onDismiss() will be invoked.