# Prevent dismissal of BottomSheetDialogFragment on touch outside

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have implemented a BottomSheet Dialog and I want to prevent the bottomsheet from dismissing when the user touches outside of the bottomsheet when it's peeking (Not fully expanded state).

I have set `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);` in the code but it doesn't seem to take any affect.

Here's my BottomSheetDialogFragment class:

```
public class ShoppingCartBottomSheetFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment  {

    private BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                dismiss();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
        super.setupDialog(dialog, style);

        View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_shopping_cart_bottom_sheet, null);

        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        dialog.setContentView(contentView);

        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) contentView.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
        CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = params.getBehavior();

        if( behavior != null && behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior ) {
            ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
            ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setPeekHeight(97);
            ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setHideable(false);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams windowParams = window.getAttributes();
        windowParams.dimAmount = 0;
        windowParams.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
        window.setAttributes(windowParams);
    }
}
```

According to the BottomSheet [specification](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-sheets.html#bottom-sheets-behavior) bottom sheets can be dismissed by touching outside of the bottom sheet, therefore what are my options to override this behavior and prevent it being dismissed?

Answer (score 63):

You should use `#setCancelable(false)` when you create an instance of it.

```
    BottomSheetDialogFragment bottomSheetDialogFragment = new SequenceControlFragmentBottomSheet();
    bottomSheetDialogFragment.setCancelable(false);
    bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), bottomSheetDialogFragment.getTag());
```

Comment: Thanks! But if you disable cancellation, you won't be able to call touch outside listeners (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616833/bottomsheetdialogfragment-listen-to-dismissed-by-user-event). For instance, if you later want to cancel the dialog in specific cases and will try to override `onCancel()` and `onStateChanged()` events, they won't call.

Comment: this is not working ,it is getting dismissed while scrolling down or touching outside the bottomsheet

Answer (score 30):

all of the above answers are a little complex in case of simple bottom sheet dialog Just Use cancellable As it prevents the scrolling and clicking outside of the Dialog.

```
mBottomSheetDialog.setCancelable(false)
```

```
mBottomSheetDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
```

just use it for simple Bottom Sheet Dialog.
it worked for Me.

Comment: plain and simple answer! :)

Comment: Worked. Add only `mBottomSheetDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)` if you need to make the bottom sheet dialog fragment persistent on screen

Answer (score 26):

`setCancelable(false)` will prevent the bottom sheet dismiss on back press also. If we look at the layout resource for the bottom sheet in android design support library, there is a *View* component with ID `touch_outside` and there is an `OnClickListener` set in method `wrapInBottomSheet` of `BottomSheetDialog`, which is used for detecting clicks outside and dismiss the dialog. So, to prevent cancel on touch outside the bottom sheet we need to remove the `OnClickListener`.

Add these line to `onActivityCreated` method (or any other life cycle method after `onCreateView`).

```
@Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    View touchOutsideView = getDialog().getWindow()
        .getDecorView()
        .findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.touch_outside);
    touchOutsideView.setOnClickListener(null);
}
```

Also if you want to prevent the bottom sheet dismiss by swiping down, change the bottom sheet dialog behaviour *Hideable* false. To `setHideable(false)` add the following code to the `onCreateDialog` method.

```
@Override public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog =
        (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    bottomSheetDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
      @Override public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
        FrameLayout bottomSheet =
        bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);

        if (null != bottomSheet) {
          BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        behavior.setHideable(false);
        }
      }
    });
    return bottomSheetDialog;
  }
```

Comment: **Note**: This works in `onActivityCreated`, however it does not work in `onViewCreated` despite it coming after `onCreateView`.

Comment: Thanks for `onActivityCreated`. @AdamHurwitz, yes, for `onViewCreated` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45614271/bottomsheetdialogfragment-doesnt-show-full-height-in-landscape-mode, there you can use `addOnGlobalLayoutListener`.

Comment: See also https://medium.com/@betakuang/make-your-bottomsheetdialog-noncancelable-e50a070cdf07. For AndroidX use `com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet` (I didn't test).

Comment: You are genius! Your `onActivityCreated` method helped me very much. I read https://medium.com/@anitas3791/android-bottomsheetdialog-3871a6e9d538, it worked, but I couldn't disable dismiss of `BottomSheetDialogFragment` in one case and enable in the other. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/55726976/2914140.

Comment: Can I override the onClick to COLLAPSE the bottomsheet when clicked outside?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/61813321/2914140 to access `behavior` simplier.

Comment: For AndroidX, it's `com.google.android.material.R.id.touch_outside` you need to get, not `design_bottom_sheet`

Comment: This works just fine. Also thanks to @Pierre-OlivierDybman for updating the correct reference for the `id`. I have added one more solution with addon below.

Answer (score 18):

Simplest way is to set **`setCanceledOnTouchOutside`** to false on the BottomSheetDialogFragment's dialog. with Kotlin,

```
class XFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        dialog?.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I could see a lot of answers but could not get them to work unltil found this one nice bolg post [here](https://medium.com/@betakuang/make-your-bottomsheetdialog-noncancelable-e50a070cdf07)

Here's one more solution on top of what is proposed by user @shijo above. All I did for my `BottomSheetDialogFragment` is just following code snippet inside `onActivityCreated` and was able to achieve these two behaviors.

- disable the draggable behavior.
- disable the cancel on touch outside.

  ```
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    val dialog = dialog as BottomSheetDialog?

    val bottomSheet =
        dialog?.findViewById<FrameLayout>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
    val behavior: BottomSheetBehavior<View> = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet as View)
    behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
    behavior.peekHeight = 0

    // Disable Draggable behavior
    behavior.isDraggable = false

    // Disable cancel on touch outside
    val touchOutsideView =
        getDialog()?.window?.decorView?.findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.touch_outside)
    touchOutsideView?.setOnClickListener(null)
  ```

This worked wonders for me. Since my bottomsheet UX demanded it to be non-cancelable and non-draggable, I was able to achieve it correctly with these changes.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by **M. Erfan Mowlaei** is useful but I was looking for a way to enforce this behavior every time an instance of the class is created without having to remember to call `setCancelable(false)`. See below.

```
class MyBottomSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

companion object {
    fun newInstance() = MyBottomSheet().apply {
        isCancelable = false
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try Kotlin way

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            dialog?.setCancelable(false)
            dialog?.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
            view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
                val dialog = dialog as BottomSheetDialog?
                val bottomSheet =
                    dialog!!.findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet) as FrameLayout
                val behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)
                behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
                behavior.peekHeight = 0
                behavior.isDraggable = false
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In kotlin is so simple , you can do it like this ;

```
class MyBottomSheetDialog : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
/*********/

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) =
        super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState).apply {
            setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
            setOnShowListener { expand() } /**to Expand your bottomSheet according to the content**/
        }

/*******/

}
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, I was looking for the opposite, to close the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` when I click outside:

```kotlin
class MyBottomSheetDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    ...
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog =
        super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState).apply {
            setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)
        }
}
```

To disable the canceling on outside click, just set the value to `false`

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the answers but here is the best working solution

**The only thing that worked for me**

**Style.xml**

```
<style name="BottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize|stateAlwaysVisible</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheet</item>
</style>

<!-- set the rounded drawable as background to your bottom sheet -->
<style name="BottomSheet" parent="@style/Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_bottom_sheet_dialog_fragment</item>
</style>
```

**RoundedBottomSheetDialogFragment**

```
open class RoundedBottomSheetDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun getTheme(): Int = R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), theme)
    }

}

class UserDetailsSheet : RoundedBottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    init {
        isCancelable = false
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_info_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
        dialog.setCancelable(false)
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        return dialog
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think all the above answers are a little incomplete, I will explain the reason why.

1. setCancelable will stop outside click behavior but it will also stop your bottomsheetDialoagFragment from back press.
2. Few answers are overriding the setCancelable() method to manage click outside, which is little complex as you will need to handle cancelable and hideable.

**Solution**

```
override fun onStart() {
       super.onStart()
       stopOutsideClick()
}

private fun stopOutsideClick() {
       val touchOutsideView = dialog?.window?.decorView?.findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.touch_outside)
       touchOutsideView?.setOnClickListener(null)
}
```

you will have to call this method in onStart() where instance of dialog will always be there.

Comment: That's a very good way to intercept the closing of the BottomSheet if you want to validate some data or ask the user if he really wants to exit before closing.

Answer (score 1):

simple and short working solution

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    }
```

override `onActivityCreated()` method of BottomSheetDialogFragment in your customDialogFragment and `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)`

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue. But I needed to prevent bottom sheet fragment from close by click outside but to leave opportunity to close by swipe down. Just add variable `isHideable: Boolean` to your BSFragment class and add next snippet

```
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
    dialog.setOnShowListener {
        val d = dialog as BottomSheetDialog
        val bottomSheet =
            d.findViewById<FrameLayout>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
        BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet!!).state = initialState()
        BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setHideable(isHideable)
    }
    return dialog
}
```

and when you call your fragment - set isHideable to true

```
private fun showBSFragmentDialog() {
  val bSFDialog = BSFragment.newInstance()
  bSFDialog.isCancelable = false
  bSFDialog.isHideable = true
  bSFDialog.show(supportFragmentManager, "bSFDialog")  }
```

now user cannot close it by click outside but able to swipe down and close dialog