# Bottom Sheet custom behaviour on outside click

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-dialogfragment, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

I use a Modal Bottom Sheet to allow the user to enter some text and create Decisions or Tasks.

[image: KEYBOARD SHOWN]

[image: KEYBOARD HIDDEN]

Some users want to close the keyboard and they `tap outside` of the `Bottom Sheet` and close it. This is a big issue because all the text is lost.

The material design [documentation](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-sheets.html#bottom-sheets-behavior) states that it can be dismissed when the outside is touched but this doesn't work for me.

I want to intercept the `onOutsideClick` event and check the keyboard's state:

- Keyboard shown: Close the soft keyboard
- Keyboard hidden: Dismiss the `Bottom Sheet`

Should I use a custom `BottomSheetBehavior` or can I `Override` some dialog methods?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42154321/prevent-dismissal-of-bottomsheetdialogfragment-on-touch-outside.