# How to disable BottomSheetDialogFragment getting dismissed on outside touch

Tags: android, android-layout

On click of button, screen presents a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` but when I touch outside on the window, it gets dismissed.

Is there a way to disable it like we do for dialog using api `setCanceledOnTouchOutside`. I have tried using setting up `setCanceledOnTouchOutside = false` in `onCreateDialog` method of my class (which extends `BottomSheetDialogFragment`) but no luck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42154321/prevent-dismissal-of-bottomsheetdialogfragment-on-touch-outside and https://medium.com/@betakuang/make-your-bottomsheetdialog-noncancelable-e50a070cdf07

Answer (score 0):

I suggest set false in `setCancelable`,   it will work for you

```
BottomSheetDialogFragment btmSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialogFragment();
btmSheetDialog.setCancelable(false);
btmSheetDialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), btmSheetDialog.getTag());
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to do like below

```
val bottomSheetDialogFragment = BottomSheetDialogFragment()
        bottomSheetDialogFragment.isCancelable = false
        bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, bottomSheetDialogFragment.tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on DialogFragment document

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html#setCancelable(boolean)

Control whether the shown Dialog is cancelable. Use this instead of directly calling `Dialog.setCancelable(boolean)`, because DialogFragment needs to change its behavior based on this.

```
Params:
cancelable – If true, the dialog is cancelable. The default is true.
```

You may try this :

**In Kotlin**

```
   val switchAccountBottomSheet = SwitchAccountBottomSheet()
   switchAccountBottomSheet.isCancelable = false
   switchAccountBottomSheet.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), SwitchAccountBottomSheet.class.getName());
```

**In Java**

```
SwitchAccountBottomSheet mSwitchAccountBottomSheet = new SwitchAccountBottomSheet();
mSwitchAccountBottomSheet.setCancelable(false);
mSwitchAccountBottomSheet.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), SwitchAccountBottomSheet.class.getName());
```