# How to dismiss Bottom Sheet fragment when click outside in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheetdialog

I make bottom sheet fragment like this:

```
val bottomSheet = PictureBottomSheetFragment(fragment)
bottomSheet.isCancelable = true
bottomSheet.setListener(pictureListener)
bottomSheet.show(ac.supportFragmentManager, "PictureBottomSheetFragment")
```

But its not dismiss when I touch outside. and dismiss or **isCancelable** not working.

Comment: Hello. Check accepted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/q/38185902/2940733.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN));
```

Comment: if you couldn't solve your problem, can you try this   -> behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED)

Answer (score 0):

You can override method and indicate, for example, in `onViewCreated` what you need:

```
class ModalDialogSuccsesDataPatient : ModalDialog() {
   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
       isCancelable = false //or true
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to design reusable functions to solve this problem and similar ones if the need arises.

We can create extension functions on `View` that tell whether a point on the screen is contained within the `View` or not.

```kotlin
fun View.containsPoint(rawX: Int, rawY: Int): Boolean {
    val rect = Rect()
    this.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect)

    return rect.contains(rawX, rawY)
}

fun View.doesNotContainPoint(rawX: Int, rawY: Int) = !containsPoint(rawX, rawY)
```

Now we can override the `dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent)` method of `Activity` to know where exactly the user clicked on the screen.

```kotlin
private const val SCROLL_THRESHOLD = 10F // To filter out scroll gestures from clicks
    
private var downX = 0F
private var downY = 0F
private var isClick = false

override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    when (event.action and MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            downX = event.x
            downY = event.y
            isClick = true
        }

        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
            val xThreshCrossed = abs(downX - event.x) > SCROLL_THRESHOLD
            val yThreshCrossed = abs(downY - event.y) > SCROLL_THRESHOLD

            if (isClick and (xThreshCrossed or yThreshCrossed)) {
                isClick = false
            }
        }

        MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            if (isClick) onScreenClick(event.rawX, event.rawY)
        }

        else -> { }
    }

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
}

private fun onScreenClick(rawX: Float, rawY: Float) { }
```

Now, you can simply use the above-defined functions to achieve the required result

```kotlin
private fun onScreenClick(rawX: Float, rawY: Float) {
    if (bottomSheet.doesNotContainPoint(rawX.toInt(), rawY.toInt())) {
        // Handle bottomSheet state changes
    }
}
```

What more? If you have a `BaseActivity` which is extended by all your `Activities` then you can add the click detection code to it. You can make the `onScreenClick` an `protected open` method so that it can be overridden by the sub-classes.

```kotlin
protected open fun onScreenClick(rawX: Float, rawY: Float) { }
```

Usage:

```kotlin
override fun onScreenClick(rawX: Float, rawY: Float) {
    super.onScreenClick(rawX, rawY)
       
    if (bottomSheet.doesNotContainPoint(rawX.toInt(), rawY.toInt())) {
        // Handle bottomSheet state changes
    }
}
```