# Override onCancel in BottomSheetFragment to setState to COLLAPSED

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheetdialog

I am trying to implement a BottomSheet using BottomSheetFragment which collapses when user clicks outside the dialog. I have tried overriding `onCancel` but to set the state to `STATE_COLLAPSED`, but it does not work - the BottomSheet disappears when clicked outside. Also have `setHideable(false)`. So, I am expecting the bottomsheet to collapse when the user clicks outside, which is not the case. How can I achieve this?

```
public class MyBottomSheet extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.eazyotp_auto_capture_bottomsheet, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onCancel(dialog);
        behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED); // does not work

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        behavior = getDialog().getBehavior();
        behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        behavior.setHideable(false);
        behavior.setPeekHeight(70); 
       // following works well - even when user drags the bottomsheet it gets into collapsed state.
        imageView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if(behavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED)
            behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        else
            behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    });

    }
}
```

Also when I do `setCancelable(false)`, I cant use collapse/expand on the `imageView`

Comment: So you want to disappear dialog when user click outside? Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52629439/1318946) your answer?

Answer (score 1):

add this in activityCreted `getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)`

Comment: Thanks. But this does not collapse the BottomSheet, it stays in expanded state.

Comment: sorry my mistake make it true

Comment: Won't this trigger onCancel normally as it does now? It wont collapse the sheet.

Comment: than make it false and setCancalable(false)